# Reflect a point across a line using affine transform

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I'm trying to reflect a point `(6,12)` across the line `y=7` using an affine transformation. Logically, the line `y=7` should be halfway the Y coordinate 12 and the Y coordinate of the answer, so `(12+Y)/2=7`, or `12+Y=14`, or `Y=2`, so the answer is `(6,2)`.

Wikipedia has examples of affine transformations at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#In_plane_geometry.

The approach I'm trying is 'translate Y -7', then 'reflect about X axis', then 'translate Y +7', leading me to believe I need these three transforms:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 7 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -14 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But if I then multiply this with my point `(6,12)` I get the wrong answer:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & -14 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\
12 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\
-26 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

And if I switch around the two translation steps, the sign of the translation changes and I do get the correct answer:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 14 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
.
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\
12 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
6 \\
2 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This gives the correct answer, but now I don't understand *why* this works, geometrically speaking! Shouldn't the positive Y transform now translate the point `(2,12)` to `(2,19)`, then reflect that to `(2,-19)` and translate that to `(2,-12)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is correct but the matrix doesn't reflect what you intended: it's in the reverse order. Suppose you have 3 transforms $A$, $B$, $C$, applied in that order. The result of first transformation on a vector $p$ is $q=Ap$, followed by the next transformation $r=Bq$ and finally $s=Cr$. If you substitute the intermediate results one by one you get $s=CBAp$.

Comment: Very helpful response. +1

Answer (score 1):

To reflect about the plane $\mathbf{n} \cdot (\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r_0} ) = 0 $, ($\mathbf{n}$ is a unit vector), the affine transformation is

$ T(\mathbf{p}) = \mathbf{r_0} + A (\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{r_0} ) $

where

$A = \mathbf{I} - 2 {\mathbf{n}\mathbf{n}}^T $

In this case, the plane is $y = 7$, so $\mathbf{n} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{r_0} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 7 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Matrix $A$ is

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} - 2 \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Using the formula for reflection,

$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 12 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 7 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && -1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 6 - 0\\ 12 - 7 \\ 0 - 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 2\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Note that I am using the $3D$ coordinates not homogeneous coordinates in $2D$.

Comment: Thanks but, respectfully, I don't see how that answers my question. I'm asking why I'm supposed to do the transformations in what feels to me like the wrong order (translate away from X axis, reflect, translate closer to X axis). Your answer derives the reflection matrix I had taken as a given from the wikipedia article, then uses a different approach to arrive at the answer: take the difference in the Y dimension of point p with the line, and add the negative of that to the original line -- which works, but doesn't help me understand my error in the more general affine transformation process.

Comment: If the first transformation is $T_1$, and the second transformation is $T_2$, then their combination is $T_2 T_1$

Comment: That's unexpected, but it does make sense now!